# Why this command works correctly in command line but doesn't in autostart file?

Tags: camera, video, raspicam

This command works in command line but doesn't in autostart:

```
raspivid -t 10000 --segment 2000  --output video_%d.h264
```

Comment: Probably need full path to raspivid

Comment: ... and maybe a full path to the destination file?

Comment: I don't know where you want to write this command and how to activate it ... but it may help you to describe the different methods for autostart. https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/

Comment: What autostart file do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Often that kind of problem is because of environment variables.

I would probably change the autostart command to:

```
strace -o /tmp/strace.out taspivid -t 10000 ....
```

Then look through strace.out to see if what it's unhappy about.